# How can I open command prompt in the current directory as a shortcut

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, shortcut

I'm just wondering how I can make a shortcut that will open command prompt in the folder it is currently in.

Why I need this.

1. I save my c program file in the directory `Users\PC\Documents\Other\My_Programs\WIP\Project_1\Test\`
2. So I would have to type `cd Users\PC\Documents\Other\My_Programs\WIP\Project_1\Test\` every time I want to open the command prompt in that directory.

Is there a shortcut I can make where I can move that shortcut around anywhere (don't need to change the shortcut) and it will open command prompt in the directory it is current in, so I don't need to keep typing `cd .....`

Comment: Do you mean something like {Shift+Right-Click} and "Windows Command Prompt" in Explorer (avaliable since Windows Vista, I think)?

Answer (score 0):

you can go to the directory and just type `start .` in the same directory

or you can make a batch file like test.bat and add below line in the same:

```
cd Users\PC\Documents\Other\My_Programs\WIP\Project_1\Test\
```

Save it anywhere and whenever you will run that batchfile, it will automatically move PWD to the required directory

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click in the open space of your desktop and click **New** > **Shortcut**
2. For the location, type or copy and paste one of the following lines.

   `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /k cd Users\PC\Documents\Other\My_Programs\WIP\Project_1\Test\`

Comment: Is there a way to make it so the shortcut code doesn't include the actual `Users\PC\Documents\Other\My_Programs\WIP\Project_1\Test\` directory. Instead it automatically finds the directory it is currently in.

Comment: Target: `cmd /k`. Start in: `%cd%`. Works with Win7. Actually leave Start in *blank* as `%cd%` is possibly ignored.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl), you can already do it, *(may be OS dependent)*!

In Windows Explorer, *or I suppose the desktop*, just hold down the shift key, right click in a blank area of it and choose **`Open command window here`**, *(or whatever your locale states)*.

*I think in Windows 10 at least, the option is even available in the Explorer toolbar menu too.*